# Most are loathe to admit that

Tags: word-usage

Is the word "loathe" here an adjective? It appears to be a verb - but I don't understand how the grammar works (with the structure "be + verb".

> Most are loathe to admit that the United States has any imperial pretensions.

> Source:  The Untold History of the United States by Oliver Stone and Peter Kuznick

Comment: It's an adjective that should be spelt "loath". The infinitival clause "to admit that the United States ..." functions as its complement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word is used here as an adjective, but it is misspelled. "Loathe" is a verb, "loath" is an adjective.

[AHD loath](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=loath)
adj.  Unwilling or reluctant; disinclined: I am loath to go on such short notice.

[AHD loathe](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=loathe)
tr.v.  To dislike (someone or something) greatly; abhor.

Answer (score 3):

They are two different words: 'Loath' and 'Loathe'. 'Loath' is an adjective but 'loathe' is a verb.

It would be:

> Most are loath to admit that...

Loathe would be used in a sentence like this:

> I loathe having to admit that...